# Set Dial function of Dialer

Tags: go, dns

I am trying to get DNS requests to tunnel through my company's proxy by using the HTTP CONNECT method.

The [library](https://github.com/miekg/dns) I am using to make the DNS requests supports setting a custom `net.Dialer` on an instance of [`dns.Client`](https://github.com/miekg/dns/blob/master/client.go#L30-L45). I found [another library](https://github.com/mwitkow/go-http-dialer) that claims to act as a drop-in replacement for `net.Dialer` that supports initiating TCP connections through a proxy using the HTTP CONNECT method.

However, I can't figure out how to get this to work with these two libraries.

I have tried setting the `Dialer` field of `dns.Client`, but it complains about incompatible types:

```
client := &dns.Client{
    Net:     "tcp",
    Timeout: time.Duration(forwarder.Timeout) * time.Second,
}

if forwarder.Proxy != nil {
    client.Dialer = http_dialer.New(forwarder.Proxy, http_dialer.WithDialer(client.Dialer))
}
```

Yields:

```
cannot use http_dialer.New(forwarder.Proxy, http_dialer.WithDialer(client.Dialer)) (type *http_dialer.HttpTunnel) as type *net.Dialer in assignment
```

So I tried casting it:

```
client := &dns.Client{
    Net:     "tcp",
    Timeout: time.Duration(forwarder.Timeout) * time.Second,
}

if forwarder.Proxy != nil {
    client.Dialer = net.Dialer(*http_dialer.New(forwarder.Proxy, http_dialer.WithDialer(client.Dialer)))
}
```

But that yields:

```
cannot convert *http_dialer.New(forwarder.Proxy, http_dialer.WithDialer(client.Dialer)) (type http_dialer.HttpTunnel) to type net.Dialer
```

Finally, I tried setting the `Dial` function of `dns.Client.Dialer` to the `Dial` function in the `http_dialer.HttpTunnel` returned by `http_dialer#New`:

```
client := &dns.Client{
    Net:     "tcp",
    Timeout: time.Duration(forwarder.Timeout) * time.Second,
}


if forwarder.Proxy != nil {
    client.Dialer.Dial = http_dialer.New(forwarder.Proxy, http_dialer.WithDialer(client.Dialer)).Dial
}
```

But that yielded:

```
cannot assign to client.Dialer.Dial
```

So I how do I set the `Dialer` of my DNS client?

Comment: There is a proxy that you have (or want) to tunnel through to reach the internet, but you can't resolve the proxy's name without also tunneling DNS through it? This sounds like chicken-egg to me.

Comment: This isn't for resolving the proxy's name, this is for resolving names of things that aren't on our network.

Comment: The proxy does that though. If I proxy a request for stackoverflow.com, my host never resolves that name. It just sends `CONNECT https://stackoverflow.com/ HTTP/1.1` to the proxy.

Comment: I know the proxy does that, this is part of a multi-application suite that makes a non-transparent proxy, transparent. As such, i need to do some sort of DNS resolution of addresses that are not on our network.